# Filtering input (numbers only) from a text with regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to figure out regex and using regexr.com to clean up a long list of GPS addresses.

The file is formatted a bit like this;

```
</extensions>
</wpt>
<wpt lat="44.9883638" lon="14.9070393">
 <name>Section 1bn</name>
```

And so far I've been able to isolate only part of the gps address by using this rule;

```
(?<=<wpt lat=").+?(?=">)
```

Using the above rule I get the following output on that website;

```
44.9883638" lon="14.9070393
```

Which is close but not ideal. What would I have to change in this rule to make the output look like this;

```
44.9883638 14.9070393
```

Comment: This picks up every number in the file and breaks it line by line, but I'd like to isolate only numbers that appear in the <wpt lat=".....> brackets.

Comment: It's better to use a XML parser, but what about [this](https://regex101.com/r/5eWvab/1)?

Comment: @Toto this seems to work correctly, however when I try to export matches, JSON and CSV formats are invalid, plain text looks correct but it puts each entry in a seperate new line, I'd like it to output like this, in one line - AA.AAAA BB.BBBB - and then the next pair of coordinates in a new line etc

Comment: [Updated regex](https://regex101.com/r/5eWvab/3). Is that what you want?

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have a long list of coordinates in a *.gpx file and want to use a text editor like Notepad++.

I also assume you only want to extract geographic coordinates.

**First step** (*you may ignore this for your needs*):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>
- Find what: `<wpt lat=".+$`
- Check `Bookmark line`
- <kbd>Mark all</kbd>

[image]

Go to Search > Bookmark > Remove Unmarked Lines.

**Second step**:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(<wpt lat=")(\d+\.\d+)(.+ lon=")(\d+\.\d+)(">)`
- Replace with: `\2 \4` (*please note there is a blank*)
- Search mode: Regular expression
- Click on <kbd>Replace All</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Dankeschoen very very much!